# Delivering power by USB C - Magnetic Framework Laptop Extension

Tags: power-supply, usb-c

I'm trying to build my own magnetic extension card for the Framework Laptop, and am trying to figure out the least number of pins I need. I have [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwAZqJ4wpJg&ab_channel=GreatScott%21) YouTube video that says the USB C PD spec needs the voltage and ground pins, along with the communication pins.

Would including just these pins from an already existing USB C charger be enough to charge at maximum power?

Edit - It seems that a teardown of a similar charger found on YouTube shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXlYNipeN9c) shows that the output USB C cable has only 3 cores, but I'm not sure which pins these connect to on the USB C connector itself.

Comment: Assuming by normal power source, you don't mean a USB-C charger, your going to need active USB-C power delivery negotiation to be able to charge at a useful rate. Probably the best bet is to identify how you are going to do that, and then Identify which pins that chip needs.

Comment: Alternatively you could put the power delivery negotiation on the card, and then only need to transfer power.

Comment: This would involve an already existing USB C charger being hooked up to a magnetic male end connector, and a female end connector which would be on the extension card itself. To do this, I would need to know exactly which pins are used for USB PD

Comment: @user1937198 sorry for not making it clear, but I do want to use a normal USB C charger and create a magnetic male end for it. I've edited the original post.